# Pendulum in an accelerating train

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration

A bob is hung from ceiling of a train.The train is moving with acceleration "a".
The bob will make angle theta=tan^-1(a/g) with the vertical.

This situation is synonymous to a one in which the train is on an incline of theta=tan^-1(a/g).The bob again makes same angle with vertical.

In suck a situation how can an observer determine if he is in an accelerating frame or not?

Can he set experiment to determine weather he is accelerating or stationary?

Comment: The two situations are not equivalent. The resultant acceleration is greater in the 1st case. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hang the bob with a spring. Spring will change length with different accelerations, but will remain the same length at different inclinations.

Comment: Note that this only works because the total force on the bob (fictitious forces included) is greater in one frame than in the other. In general, it's impossible to determine whether you're in an accelerating frame of reference or stationary in a gravitational field of equivalent magnitude; this idea underpins all of general relativity.

Comment: @spatialdelusion This answer assumes constant acceleration. In a frame with constant acceleration, the effect of the acceleration can be accounted for using a fictitious force in the opposite direction of the acceleration.

Comment: @probably_someone yes, but i wanted an explanation of Tom bs answer.His experiment works in variable acceleration only.Right?

Comment: @spatialdelusion No, this answer works with constant acceleration, for the reasons I just cited.

Comment: @probably_someone ohhh...but then what did you mean by " In general, it's impossible to determine whether you're in an accelerating frame of reference or stationary in a gravitational field of equivalent magnitude; this idea underpins all of general relativity."(since we can distinguish between accelerating and inertial frames)

Comment: @spatialdelusion The key here is the phrase _of equivalent magnitude_. It would be impossible to distinguish a pendulum in a train accelerating in zero gravity from a pendulum in a train that was stationary in a gravitational field that exerted the same force on the pendulum. Your example doesn't show this, because it has acceleration and gravity in one frame, and no acceleration, but the same amount of gravity, in the other frame.

Comment: @spatialdelusion Essentially, my point was: even though, in this example, you can distinguish between accelerating and stationary frames, don't assume that you can always do so.

Comment: I was assuming the train is on a planetary surface with known gravity. I was also assuming the word "acceleration" referred to horizontal acceleration of the train on a flat level (horizontal) surface, because OP was comparing this to a stationary train on an incline.

Comment: @spatialdelusion lookup "equivalence principal" probably_someone is indeed referring to a profound idea of general relativity.

Answer (score 2):

Tap the pendulum and time its period.  It will be shorter than expected on the accelerating train.

This is because the effective "acceleration of gravity" is greater in the accelerating train.