# The acceleration of a train where a suspended mass from a string from the trains ceiling makes an angle θ with the vertical

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, acceleration, centripetal-force

There is a mass suspended by a string from the ceiling of an accelerating train. The string makes and angle $\theta$ with the vertical as the train uniformly accelerates along a horizontal track.

[image: Mass making an angle θ to the vertical]

The question asks to find the acceleration of the train, and I thought that I could find the acceleration of the mass (using the centripetal force formula) to get it because the mass is not moving relative to the train, hence the acceleration of the mass must be the same as that of the train, right? The answer to this question is $g\tan\theta$, and I am not quite sure where this is coming from.

Comment: This question could benefit from an attempt to solve the problem. It is tagged [tag:free-body-diagram], but no diagram is given. The centripetal and tangential components of the acceleration are at right angles, so theoretically they can be easily combined to get the overall acceleration. Unfortunately, the centripetal acceleration does not have a straightforward expression in terms of $\theta$. Whoever told you that the overall acceleration is $g \tan\theta$ should have given an explanation of how to get there.

Comment: Also, I assume that when you say “pendulum”, you really mean the *end* of the pendulum. Is that right? Otherwise, this question is really confusing.

Comment: None of the variables are defined properly (except perhaps $T$), so it is hard to tell what is going on. But an overall acceleration of $g \tan\theta$ seems to imply that it is zero at some point, which is incorrect. The velocity is always changing; therefore, the acceleration is never zero.

Comment: I definitely agree that I explained in a confusing manner. Perhaps it might make more sense now since I added a picture, sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: And yes, I mean the end of the pendulum!

Comment: *Apparently the acceleration of the pendulum is $g\tan\theta$*. That cannot be correct. For $\theta=90°$$ you would get infinite acceleration, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:free-body-diagram], but no *free-body* diagram is given. Also, I say again: Whoever told you that the overall acceleration is $g \tan\theta$ should have given an explanation of how to get there. @ThomasFritsch has correctly pointed out that this formula does not make sense.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanations! I get it now that it makes no sense!

Comment: Ahmed: you still did not explain how you come to "apparently the acceleration of the pendulum is tan" it's not apparent to me!

Comment: @trula I did not want to do OP’s research for them. But my guess is that they saw this formula for a [pendulum in an accelerating train](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387346/279176), and, for some reason, applied it to this (apparently different) situation.

Comment: @Brian Drake, that is right! I am referring that question. The acceleration of the train is gtan, and since the pendulum is not moving relative to the train, their acceleration must be the same, right?

Comment: The train? What train? Why do you say the acceleration of the train is $g \tan\theta$? Do you know this, or do you need to prove it? I’m downvoting this question. Please edit the question to **state all the information** and **state a clear question**. If you improve the question, I may reverse my vote and write an answer.

Comment: @Brian Drake I agree that the question is unclear! I will improve it!

Answer (score 2):

Find the horizontal and vertical components for the tension in the string.

Comment: I got it!! So tanθ is the horizontal component over the vertical component of the tension force, hence we get that mgtanθ = Tx. Now to get the acceleration, we must divide my the mass, hence we get gtanθ.

Comment: Also, note that we must look for the horizontal acceleration as the train is accelerating horizontally.